# Docker run hello world isn't workng

Tags: docker

[image: can't use docker basic command]

I don't know why but my docker recently have been getting a lot of bugs and I even re-installed him, but anyway I'm trying to do this basic command but is not working guys 
help pls

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: shouldn't your command be docker run hello-world?

Answer (score 2):

You must search the image with:

```
docker search hello-world
```

or

```
docker search "hello world"
```

In the first line appear the correct name that is hello-world, then write:

```
docker pull hello-world
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the wrong name

use this one instead:

```
docker run hello-world
```